# How to enable adding Permission in Keycloak v21?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, keycloak

I m using Keycloak V21 and in client details I have only 6 tabs: Settings, Keys, Credentials, Roles, Sessions, Advanced.

Here is my docker-compose:

```
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2
    entrypoint: /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh
    command: start-dev
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    env_file:
      - ./apps/keycloak/.env
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

And here is my env file:

```
# keycloak
KC_HTTP_PORT: 6001

KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true

KC_DB: postgres
KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
# see: PGPORT
KC_DB_URL_PORT: 6000
KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for `docker-compose.yml` (no spaces between the features):

```
    keycloak:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        environment:
            KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
            KC_FEATURES: scripts,token-exchange,admin-fine-grained-authz
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
        volumes:
            - ./keycloak/keycloak_data:/opt/keycloak/data
```

Answer (score 0):

KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
KC_FEATURES: token-exchange,admin-fine-grained-authz

Need to add KC_FEATURES

Comment: Can you share full code of `docker-compose.yml`?